# C++ Align by structure size or largest alignment requirement among its members?

Tags: c++, memory

Take this structure for example:

```
struct Packing
{
     int x; // 4-byte align
     int y; // 4-byte align
     short int z; // 2-byte align
     char m; // 1-byte align;
     char _pad[1]; // explicit padding
};
```

The sizeof this structure is 12-bytes.

So should store this struct in addresses multiples of the struct size (12-bytes) or in multiples of sizeof(int) (the largest alignment requirement among the members of the struct)?

Since multiples of 12 are also multiples of 4 (sizeof(int)) I guess the struct will be correctly aligned in addresses multiples of 12, but I might waste space that wouldnt be wasted if it was 4-byte aligned.

**EDIT:** At address *0x00000012* the structure would be aligned and the its first member would also be aligned because 12 is a multiple of 4.
What if stored it at address *0x00000004*? In this case the first element of the struct would be aligned but what about the structure itself?

Comment: Are you trying to writing a portable code, which will run on multiple compilers?

Comment: `should store this function`, store what?

Comment: `__pad` is a reversed identifier.

Comment: it's also a reserved identifier

Comment: Oh damn :) Yeah, what Paul said.

Comment: @Mu Qiao it was a typo I meant struct

Comment: The compiler already takes care of optimum alignment (and size). There is no need to explicitly add padding 9the compiler is already better than you at correctly defining padding) the runtime already correctly aligns dynamically created objects. So what are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimal alignment for a struct is equal to the largest alignment for any of the struct's members. In this case that is 4.

**Update**

The above assumes that the primary operation you perform on the struct is accessing its members. See the comments to [Necrolis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242271/c-align-by-structure-size-or-largest-alignment-requirement-among-its-members/7242673#7242673) for more discussion. In short I suspect that the real answer to your question depends strongly on the hardware involved and the algorithms you are using.

Comment: Aligning structure elements optimizes for speed of access.  Packing structure elements optimizes for size.

Comment: Correctly aligning structures optimizes for avoiding undefined behavior and thus subtly breaking your code when you least expect it.

Comment: I'm not talking about alignment of the members of the struct but the struct itself. Should I store the struct in addresses multiples of sizeof(Packing) or sizeof(int) which is the largest member?

Comment: I know what you are talking about. My answer already answers the question in this comment.

Comment: So just to make it clear: If the main objective is to access members of the structure the optimal alignment for the struct is equal to the largest alignment for any of the struct's members. On the other hand, if the main objective is copying the struct (or other actions that use the struct as a whole) aligning it like 'Necrolis' gives better performance right?

Comment: @tiago I think your statement is probably true in general, although I'm sure you could find exceptions for certain operations on certain platforms!

Comment: @David Heffernan Of course, but that's like almost everything else in programming for multi-platform

Answer (score 5):

if you want to align for performance on any intel CPU, you should follow these guidelines from the intel optimization manual:

> For best performance, align data as follows:
>
> • Align 8-bit data at any address.
>
> • Align 16-bit data to be contained within an aligned 4-byte word.
>
> • Align 32-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of four.
>
> • Align 64-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of eight.
>
> • Align 80-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of sixteen.
>
> • Align 128-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of sixteen.

so in your case, you would align by 16, *not* 4 or 8, as your struct falls between 64 and 128 bits in length, 16 is the best upper fit, it also enables some other extra stuff, like being able to use SIMD to copy the struct(s) around.

Comment: There's a misthink here. The struct isn't accessed in its entirety. Its members are accessed. This struct only needs to be aligned on 32 bit boundaries.

Comment: @David: no, thats for access to the struct *members*

Comment: Accessing the members is all you can do with a struct!  Pray tell, what would you do with a 1000 bit struct?

Comment: @David: you can copy it, stream to to a GPU etc. things like cache lines also need to be taken into account

Comment: Hmm. Most significant penalties are for misaligned reads/writes/ops of members, but not so much on x86. There's also a balance between alignment and space when it comes to cache. Using 16 byte alignment rather than 12 byte for this struct would result in 25% more cache misses. I wouldn't mind betting that some algorithms would be better with 12 byte alignment, and others with 16 byte alignment.

Comment: @David: and an alignment of 12 will cause cache line splits, it basically depends what you are optimizing for, speed or size.

Comment: It also depends on which is worse, and by how much, a split or a miss

Comment: @David: agreed, which means this would be up to a hardware based profiler to decide :P

Comment: I've added some weasel words to my answer and up-voted yours. Nothing is ever straightforward.

Comment: @David: thats gentlemanly of you, thanks :) if only things where straight forward :P

Comment: 16byte alignment all the way. SIMD not just for move/copy, but also zeroing out a newly allocated array.

Comment: So should I align the structs by the nearest upper power of two? Example: 60-byte struct -> 64-byte align?

Comment: @Tiago: not power of two, but rather multiple of 16 for sizes less than 49 else 64, but that changes depending on how you use the memory and your constraints, its best to read the intel optimization manual yourself, as you may get a better understanding. Also, it should be noted that you can rearrange the struct to change its alignment needs if it has 'odd' members

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is allowed to leave whatever gaps it wants to ensure that it can access the structure efficiently. Exactly what is needed depends on the underlying architecture. If you are using a 32 bit architecture and there are no half-word or byte data loads, the compiler will probably align all data members (including z, m and _pad) to word boundaries. If however the architecture can do efficient half-word and byte data loads, the you will probably find your struct has the expected `sizeof(Packing) == 12`